# ScrollView not working within Coordinator and Relative layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

The following code display only 3 of 4 `Editext` within a `ScrollView`.
The problem is the last `Editext` which is overlapping the `Button`

Why ScrollView isn't working properly?

Or How avoid this overlaps?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/cl"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bt_next">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_activity_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/mysv">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Input 1"/>


            <View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="150dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Input 2"/>

            <View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="150dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Input 3"/>

            <View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="150dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Input 4"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_next"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Next"/>
```

This is how looks like at the end of the scroll.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the ScrollView, your problem is the fact that you have the `Button` floating out by itself outside of the CoordinatorLayout.
If you're trying to get the content above the button, you could try adding `alignToTopOf="@id/bt_next` (I forget the exact name of the attribute, but you get the idea). Then the Coordinator should sit on top of the button.

If that's not what you're trying to do, post a screenshot of what you're trying to get to and a screenshot of what's broken now.

Comment: You also have `layout_alignParentBottom`. You want the button aligned to the bottom of the RelativeLayout but above the Coordinator? That combination makes no sense. Again, posting screenshots would help.

Comment: You haven't posted screenshots so I have no idea what the final layout actually looks like. I will say that Coordinator layout should usually be the root view, not be put inside a RelativeLayout. So try moving your RelativeLayout inside the Coordinator. Once again, screenshots would be supremely helpful.

Comment: Ok, now it's wierd. When keyboard shows up then input4 stops overlaps but the toolbar is gone until I restart the activity.

Comment: What kind of screenshots? It's an overlap, i can upload screenshots but i don't see any sense.

Comment: Screenshot of what you want vs what you have. An "overlap" to you could mean 50 different things to me. A picture is worth a thousand words and all that.

Comment: I want avoid the overlaps. I've uploaded how it looks like.

Comment: Did you try moving the RelativeLayout inside of the CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: AFAIK CoordinatorLayout is a superpower framelayout. So I need to use RelativeLayout in order to set the Button at bottom.

Comment: You can still use the RelativeLayout, just have it nest inside the CoordinatorLayout. CoordinatorLayout should be your root view.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved using `Nestedlayout` and a `LinearLayout` inside.
The key is keep in mind `CoordinatorLayout` works as a `FrameLayout`.

The only issue that I find is the toolbar is not hiding when I scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bt_next"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">



        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mysv">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_activity_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/mysv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Input 1"/>


                <View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="150dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Input 2"/>

                <View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="150dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Input 3"/>

                <View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="150dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Input 4"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Next"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```